# Decommissioning a node from cluster is stuck and no clue from logs what went wrong

Tags: cassandra

We have initiated decommissioning a node from 18 node cluster and I see there is no progress and still showing the status as LEAVING. The same activity earlier used to be completed in a day and now even after 2 days node has not decommissioned

When I checked

**nodetool netstats**:

[image]

**nodetool ring**: I see tokens are still owned by leaving node

Please guide me on what can be checked to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes file streams get stuck. Run a `nodetool netstats` on that node to see if there are any open file streams. If there are, check them every now and then to see if they are progressing. If they are not progressing, restart the node and try the decommission again.

Answer (score 0):

A node decommission can stall or not complete for various reasons and some of the factors that contribute to it are (1) how busy the cluster is, (2) how much data there is on the node, (3) streams getting interrupted.

If you haven't already, analyse the debug log (`debug.log`) and focus on the tasks that relate to the decommission. There will be task IDs that will be logged and you need to trace those tasks for clues as to why the decommission didn't complete. Cheers!